# Why am I getting "AbstractController::DoubleRenderError" when calling redirect_to in after_action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the comments controller, I am redirecting to the articles show page after both create and destroy.
So I decided to write an `after_action` which would do the `redirect_to`.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_article
  before_action :find_comment, only: [:destroy]

  after_action :goto_articles_page, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
  end

  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
  end

  private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end

    def find_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    end

    def find_comment
       @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    end

    def goto_articles_page
      redirect_to article_path(@article) and return
    end
end
```

But this gives me `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError` after both create and destroy.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: not sure if any effect but what happens when you remove `and return` from goto_articles_page

Comment: I get the error in both the cases, "with and without `and return`"

Comment: Try changing `and return` with a `return` in next  line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Rails will render views that correspond to the controller action. [See Rails Guides.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action)

So in your `create` and `destroy` actions, Rails is performing a render by default. Then your `after_action` (which happens *after* the action) is redirecting, so it's double rendering.

Instead of an `after_action`, you could call the `goto_articles_page` method in your controller actions.

For example:

```
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    goto_articles_page
  end

  def goto_articles_page
    redirect_to article_path(@article) #return not needed
  end
```

Comment: That helped. Thanks Mike :)

Answer (score 0):

I think using `return` when `rendering` any action but when `redirect_to` use then not need to use `return` then finally you can remove `and return`

[Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#avoiding-double-render-errors) very nicely explained that you can follow this carefully

[redirect_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect-to) explanation

Hope to help